# R: how to use if myValue.is.na?

Tags: r, if-statement, na

Basically, I am iterating through some values, some which may be NA. If it is NA, I'd like to set it to 0.

For example

```
    if (myValue.is.na){
    myValue=0
    }
```

Comment: No need to loop you can write : `x[is.na(x)] <- 0` where `x` is a vector of values

Comment: Thanks, but I personally prefer to loop for what I am doing (as I am using combn)

Comment: You were close. Try `if (is.na(myValue)){
    myValue <- 0
    }`

Comment: Thanks all. Dustin Knight that was exactly what I was looking for. Cheers.